# Multiple users on one computer with different monitors on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, xorg, integrated-graphics, multiple-users

I got a GTX 670, which powers my three monitors. But I got a processor with a HD4000 integrated graphics and I'd like to add a fourth monitor to the processor graphics, on which a different user works parallel to me. And it's very important that both users have the full hardware acceleration available (The GTX 670 for me and the HD4000 for the other user). I know that sounds very complicated, but I hope it's possible.

Comment: In general, it seems like what you'd need to do would be to run two X servers, one per video adapter, and each with its own configuration (including input devices, so that each user has his own keyboard and mouse). You'd also need to run one gdm per X server. I have not the slightest idea how to go about setting up such a configuration, but I'm pretty sure that would be the way to do it.

Comment: I know how to do it in theory, but I'm struggeling to get the things running.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid I really can't help you there; I'm busy switching to OS X precisely because I've spent enough years of my life screwing around with things like xorg.conf files, and am entirely sick of them. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not that easy but possible if you use linux.

In Linux you can set up multiple X servers to run concurrent.
(see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX)

I really don't know if hardware acceleration is possible for multiple X servers. It depends on your graphics card drivers.

You can also try to set separate graphic card drivers for each X server in the config file. This should work as you have an Intel and a NVIDIA gfx card.

Comment: The HD4000 is onboard graphics in the Intel CPU, not ATI.

Comment: This should not make any difference :) But thanks for the hint

Comment: The article is from 2006, do I still need to patch the kernel? And is XFree68 the same as X11?

Comment: I just updated the answer to a more up to date link :)